# i3blocks battery script, using font awesome doesn't work with some unicodes

Tags: perl, unicode, icons, font-awesome

I use font-awesome 4.4.0 and have extended the default i3blocks battery script with the new battery icons.
All seem to work correctly but the `fa-battery-half Unicode: f242`, which renders the script useless. The unicode also seems to refer to the character ``.

In the terminal it crashes with:

```
$ perl /usr/share/i3blocks/battery
Wide character in print at /usr/share/i3blocks/battery line 65.
28%  (01:02)
Wide character in print at /usr/share/i3blocks/battery line 66.
28%  
#000000
```

The script is default, except of the following few lines:

```
if ($status eq 'Discharging') {

if ($percent < 10) {
    $full_text .= '  ';
} elsif ($percent < 25) {
    $full_text .= '  ';
} elsif ($percent < 50) {
    $full_text .= '  ';
} elsif ($percent < 75) {
    $full_text .= '  ';
} elsif ($percent < 100) {
    $full_text .= '  ';
}

} elsif ($status eq 'Charging') {
    $full_text .= '  ';
}
```

and

```
if ($status eq 'Discharging') {

if ($percent < 25) {
    print "#FF003C\n";
} else {
    print "#000000\n";
}

if ($percent < 5) {
    exit(33);
}
}
```

In the editor the script looks like:

[image]

How may I get the script to work, with the `fa-battery-half Unicode: f242` icon.

Comment: If you are using UTF-8 in source code then you need to put `use utf8;` in your script.

Comment: Belongs on fonts.stackexchange.com

Comment: @mob that doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two problems.

---

Your first problem is a bug that's resulting in the "wide character" warnings and possibly other problems. To solve the error, properly encode your output. Specifically, add the following to your script:

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```

This tells Perl to

- Encode text sent to STDOUT using UTF-8.
- Encode text sent to STDERR using UTF-8.
- Decode text read from STDIN using UTF-8.
- Use UTF-8 as the default encoding for files.

The warnings indicate that Perl was able to notice your bug, and that it attempted to fix it by encoding the output using UTF-8. That's the correct fix, so your program's output won't change, which brings us to the second problem.

---

Your second problem is that your terminal's font doesn't have a glyph for U+F242. If you wish to display that character, you'll need to use a different font.

Comment: I don't quite understand why all the other icons, from the same font work, just not the one used in `} elsif ($percent < 50) {
    $full_text .= '  ';` 
Does the problem come with this specific unicode or with the icon?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: The reason of my second problem. If this has to do with the unicode itself or if there is some other reason why the terminals don't have a glyph for it.

Comment: A terminal wouldn't normally have glyphs for any of these characters as they are [private use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas) characters. Your font has glyphs for some of them, it can't handle F242.