# Some Awesome Font characters are not displayed in i3

Tags: vim, fonts, terminal, font-awesome

I'm using FontAwesome with i3wm and a few characters are not displaying (fa-home, fa-heart, fa-gear,...)
I have "font pango:DejaVu Sans Mono 8, FontAwesome 8" in my i3 config file.

Even in Character Map, I see the glyph but when I double click to copy it nothing is displayed in the "Text to copy" box.

I see them when I go to the CheatSheet but if I copy and try to paste in Vim, same thing, I don't see them.

Most of the characters are ok, only a few of them don't show.

[I'm wondering if it is related to what's sais at the end this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32181689/i3blocks-battery-script-using-font-awesome-doesnt-work-with-some-unicodes)

Any help would be appreciated as I've spend hours searching the net without success.

Best regards

[Awesome Font in Vim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywZYp.jpg)

[Awesome Font in i3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLTql.jpg)

Comment: Can you please clarify your question: do you want to use font awesome for elements of the i3 window manager or do you want to use them inside vim?

Comment: I want to use the Awesome font for element of i3 (i3blocks, workspace tabs - see screenshot).

As I use Vim, I gave a screenshot of it where the font is displayed too, to show that it displays characters properly in both i3 and Vim _excepted_ for some of them (fa-home, fa-gear,...)